# Querying on SQL Server and PostgreSQL, how I could have from first table the visualization like second table

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, t-sql

Querying on SQL Server, how I could have from first table the visualization like second table.

The logic of the “status” column for each row is:

If the number of connections of this specific row was bigger than the average of every rows, the status will be “Overload”, else “OK’.

Next the same logic using PostgreSQL, how it would be? Is there any difference in the syntax?

Table provided:

[image]

Result expected:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CASE expression with a window function:

```
select id,
       server_name,
       case
         when connections > avg(connections) over() then 'Overload' 
         else 'OK'
       end as status
from the_table
order by id;
```

The above is 100% standard ANSI SQL and should work not only on Postgres but on SQL Server as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `CASE` expression to compare the value of `Connections` with the average value which you can get with a subquery:

```
SELECT *, 
       CASE 
         WHEN Connections > (SELECT AVG(1.0 * Connections) FROM tablename) 
           THEN 'Overload' 
         ELSE 'Ok' 
       END Status
FROM tablename
```

Note that you should multiply the integer value of `Connections` by `1.0` because in SQL Server the result of `AVG()` is integer if the argument is integer, so you get a truncated value for the average.

This is not needed in Postgresql where you can remove the multiplication.